# Python fast DataFrame concatenation

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a code to concatenate parts of a DataFrame to the same DataFrame as to normalize the occurrence of rows as per a certain column.

```py
import random

def normalize(data, expectation):
    """Normalize data by duplicating existing rows"""

    counts = data[expectation].value_counts()
    max_count = int(counts.max())

    for tag, group in data.groupby(expectation, sort=False):
        array = pandas.DataFrame(columns=data.columns.values)

        i = 0
        while i < (max_count // int(counts[tag])):
            array = pandas.concat([array, group])
            i += 1

        i = max_count % counts[tag]
        if i > 0:
            array = pandas.concat([array, group.ix[random.sample(group.index, i)]])

        data = pandas.concat([data, array])

    return data
```

and this is unbelievably slow. Is there a way to fast concatenate DataFrame without creating copies of it?

Comment: This looks painful... It would be easier for other to reply if you posted some sample data.  Also, you want your concat outside of your `for` loop.  If you stored your arrays in a list and then concatenated after you loop, it would run much faster.  Again, however, there is probably a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of things that stand out.

---

To begin with, the loop

```
i = 0
while i < (max_count // int(counts[tag])):
    array = pandas.concat([array, group])
    i += 1
```

is going to be very slow. Pandas is not built for these dynamic concatenations, and I suspect the performance is quadratic for what you're doing.

Instead, perhaps you could try

```
pandas.concat([group] * (max_count // int(counts[tag]))
```

which just creates a list first, and then calls `concat` for a one-shot concatenation on the entire list. This should bring the complexity to being linear, and I suspect it will have lower constants in any case.

---

Another thing which would reduce these small `concats` is calling [`groupby-apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html). Instead of iterating over the result of `groupby`, write the loop body as a function, and call `apply` on it. Let Pandas figure out best how to concat all of the results into a single DataFrame.

However, even if you prefer to keep the loop, I'd just append things into a list, and just `concat` everything at the end:

```
stuff = []
for tag, group in data.groupby(expectation, sort=False):
    # Call stuff.append for any DataFrame you were going to concat.
pandas.concat(stuff)
```